# Update page after form submit - using Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I am using the MEAN framework - I have a basic form (as per below) that when data is entered it is sent to a rest API which then has a function that uses Mongoose to save data. That is all good... however i'm stuck on something more basic!

After a user has submitted this form it lands on a blank page with the api/img/add, how do i go back to my original page? I tried adding ng-submit="fetchImages()" within the form tag and then implementing a function in a script (also shown below) but for some reason this was not working, am i missing the point and doing something really wrong?

Thanks in advance

```
<form action="api/img/add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <div>
        <label for="image">Select an image</label>
        <input type="file" name="image" id="image">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title">
      </div>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

```js
 < script >
   angular.module('app', []).controller('main', ['$scope', '$http',
     function($scope, $http) {
       $scope.images = [];
       $scope.fetchImages = function() {
         $scope.images = [];
         $http.get('api/img').then(function(res) {
           $scope.images = JSON.parse(res.data);
         }, function(res) {
           console.log(res.statusText);
         });
       }

       $scope.fetchImages();
     }
   ]); < /script>
```

Comment: Don't set `action` if you want to submit by `$http`. That being said you need to use `FormData` api to upload images with ajax and requires telling `$http` not to process data. Suggest looking for tutorial `angular upload` or similar searches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
In html

```
    <form ng-submit="submitData()">
      <div>
        <label for="image">Select an image</label>
        <input type="file" ng-model="formdata.image" id="image">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="formdata.title" id="title">
      </div>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

In your controller:

```
 angular.module('app', []).controller('main', ['$scope', '$http',
 function($scope, $http) {

   $scope.formdata = {};
   $scope.images = [];

   $scope.fetchImages = function() {
     $scope.images = [];
     $http.get('api/img').then(function(res) {
       $scope.images = JSON.parse(res.data);
     }, function(res) {
       console.log(res.statusText);
     });
   }

   $scope.fetchImages();

   //this function will post data to your api without refreshing the page
   $scope.submitData = function(){

      $http.post('api-comes-here', $scope.formdata).then(function(res) {
          //handle success
      }, function(error) {
           //handle error
      });


   }
 }
```

Comment: thanks this is really helpful, the problem is have is that I'm not too sure what is happening with the formData when i get to the API. So my API looks like this: app.post('/api/img/add', upload.single('formData.image'), imgController.addImage()); this then uses the function from the controller which basically just uses mongoose to save the image. The problem is that the formData doesnt seem to be in the req ??

Comment: Try this:                                                                                       $http.post("api-comes-here", $scope.formdata).success(function(data, status) {

})                                                                                                                            Also check your network tab in developer tools to see if the request is going to the right URL along with the data

Comment: I checked the network tab and can see that it made the call to the correct API, but it doesnt seem to be passing any data in the req as its correctly saving an entry into mongo but with no data.

Comment: Okay, so can you check under network tabs under headers, what request payload is going ? If its blank then we have an issue, if not then you need to check API end point to fix it..

Comment: thanks for trying to help, i appreciate it. I'm using chrome developer tools, checked network but cant see payload? it seems that nothing is being passed back , should formdata be in the req?

Comment: My bad, just check my edit and it will work fine now. I replaced name with ng-model.

Comment: Also just a suggestion, you should accept image as base64. To do that you need to do this                                                                                                    <input type="file" ng-model="formdata.image"  base-sixty-four-input>

Comment: Your a star, just the image is not being uploaded now! I'm using multer but will check the details

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct if it helped. Also, you base64 input for uploading things like image/documents.

Comment: thanks again for your help!! It's still not sending the image for some reason - can you think of anything that might be wrong? It was working when i was using form action.

Comment: check this directive http://uncorkedstudios.com/blog/multipartformdata-file-upload-with-angularjs                                                                                                      You can include it in your project and make input like  <input name="file" type="file" id="file" file-model="fileToUpload" /> and in submit Data function you should write $scope.formdata.image = $scope.fileToUpload

Answer (score 1):

If you literally want to go back to the last page, you could use:

```
$window.history.back();
```

In your example, I would create the function in the controller as outlined below, and change

```
<input type="submit">
```

to

```
<input type="submit" ng-click="goHome()">
```

---

I created an über-simple plunk here with a button that will take you back:

https://plnkr.co/edit/wzMlPF9kOmrGg01mOnBB?p=preview

**JS**

```
app.controller('ctrl',function($scope,$window){

  $scope.goHome = function() {
    $window.history.back();
  }

});
```

**HTML**

```
<button ng-click="goHome()">Go Home</button>
```

Comment: I should have called the function goBack(), but I am tired :(